# Adding datetime by 1 hour implementation to existing dataset with (dumb question)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have 3 columns in the dataset to which I wanna add dates

| Date | temperature | humidity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 5.9 | NA |
| 2015-01-01 01:00:00 | 5.5 | NA |
| ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ |
| 2015-01-01 23:00:00 | 7 | NA |

I wanna add 2 months like from 1st may to 31 july to Date column
with hour implementation it will be smth like this

| Date | temperature | humidity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ |
| 2015-01-01 23:00:00 | 7 | NA |
| 2015-05-01 00:00:00 | .. | NA |
| 2015-05-01 01:00:00 | .. | NA |
| ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ |

until i get to

| Date | temperature | humidity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ |
| 2015-07-31 23:00:00 | .. | NA |

I've tried

```py
date = datetime.datetime(2015,3,31,23,0,0)
for i in range(32): 
    date += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    print(date)
```

is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: What did you try? Python or R?

Comment: I'm a beginner, i'm trying with python

Comment: so, did you load the dataset in a Python script? To which data structure (dictionary, pandas.DataFrame, ...)?

Comment: I did load them, generated the dates but can't figure out how to add them to the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a start with the iteration from `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedelta`

You need to accumulate those in a list, rather than printing them

```py
listofdates=[]
date = datetime.datetime(2015,3,31,23,0,0)
for i in range(32): 
    date += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    listofdates.append(date)
```

And then, create a new dataframe from the existing one (let's call it df) and this list of dates. Do do so, you can use `pd.concat` that creates a dataframe from two dataframes.
So, you need a dataframe from your new list of dates. With the same column name

```py
newlines = pd.DataFrame({'Date':listofdates})
```

Which gives

| Date |
| --- |
| 2015-04-01 00:00:00 |
| ⋮ |
| 2015-04-02 07:00:00 |

(Note that it starts at 4/1 00:00, not 3/31 23:00, because you add the timedelta beform appending)

We can concatenate your dataframe with this one (missing columns will be filled with `NA`) like this

```py
newdf = pd.concat([df, newlines])
```

Last remarks that I kept for the end to avoid confusion:

1. I would have stored the timedelta once for all, rather than creating one each time (it is not that expansive, but still)

So, altogether

```py
date=datetime.datetime(2015,3,31,23,0,0)
dt=datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
listofdates=[]
for i in range(32): 
    date += dt
    listofdates.append(date)
newlines = pd.DataFrame({'Date':listofdates})
newdf = pd.concat([df, newlines])
```

2. For this kind of usage, you can build the list directly using compound lists

```py
listofdates=[date+k*dt for k in range(1,33)]
```

Or using numpy

```py
listofdates=date+np.arange(1,33)*dt
```

Which allows for one-liner

```py
newdf = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'Date':date+np.arange(1,33)*dt})])
```

But don't try to understand this one before you understood the longer version previously described

Comment: can't I add them to the existing column date ?

Comment: Not in a dataframe no. What you do is adding rows. You can't add new values to one column only. A postulate of dataframes is that all columns has the same number of rows (and all rows the same number of columns). Note that I almost did that, since I concat a dataframe made of just the column 'Date' to your dataframe. But that will implicitly create the 2 other columns during concatenation)